# Python - Press key after certain program runs

Tags: windows-10, automation, tasks

So I have this program that has to be running 24/7, and whenever it crashes, this window pops up

[image: Window I have to press "ok/enter" on]

And all I wanted to schedule is an enter keypress whenever either this program runs or this window pops up.

I've tried creating an event with the log being an application but I can't choose which application it is, anyone know a solution?

EDIT: So I found a really simple solution for my problem using a python script, here it is if anyone is interested!

```
import pyautogui
import win32gui

while True:
    if win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Blacklist"):
        handle = win32gui.FindWindow(0, "Blacklist")
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle)
        pyautogui.typewrite(['enter', 'enter'])
```

Comment: Task Scheduler can't do this. But there is software that can do this. I use something myself that costs money but it can do it. I'm sure there are also freeware programs to automatically dismiss a popup window (which this basically is)

Comment: Can you tell me the name of said software you use?

Comment: Start the application as a service. Standard service management system can restart service if it crashes or hangs without any popup.

Comment: How do I start the application as a service?

Comment: I use Actual Tools Window Manager, which is their total package. All features also have their own cheaper app.

Comment: [RunAsService project](https://github.com/luisperezphd/RunAsService)

Comment: You should post your findings as an answer so you can mark it solved in 2 days. That way, others know you no longer need help.